# ¿Cómo graficar en diferentes "planos" (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Tengo lo siguiente:

**Código: **

```
            import math
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            import numpy as np

            fn_1 = np.sin
            fn_2 = np.cos

            x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 1000)
            points = [i * np.pi/2 for i in range(-4, 5)]
            labels = ["-2π", "-3π/2", "-π", "-π/2", "0", "π/2", "π", "3π/2", "2π"]

            fig, ax  = plt.subplots()
            ax.plot(x, fn_1(x))
            ax.plot(x, fn_2(x))
            ax.set_xticks(points)
            ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

            for pt in points:

                ax.plot(pt, fn_1(pt), "ok")
                ax.plot(pt, fn_2(pt), "ok")

            ax.hlines(0, x[0], x[-1], "k")
            ax.vlines(0, -1, 1, "k")

            plt.show()
```

**Resultado: **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión ahora es que quiero que grafique las funciones de forma individual, es decir, un plano para la función seno y otro para la función coseno.

También quiero colocarles etiquetas a las funciones, es decir, que me diga, por ejemplo, que la función en azul es la gráfica del seno y la naranja del coseno. ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tener gráficas separadas en una misma ventana se necesita crear una instancia de `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` y con ayuda de un ciclo `for` ir añadiendo las gráficas p *sub-plots*, en cuanto a la etiqueta, eso se llama `label` que asigna un nombre a cada grafica creada.

```py
#creamos la instancia de figure con el nombre planos
fig1 = plt.figure("planos", figsize=(30,30)) #figsize es una tupla de valores (ancho, alto)
fig1.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5) #separación por cada gráfica creada

#ponemos las funciones en una lista
funciones = [fn_1(x), fn_2(x)]

for i,f in zip(range(1,3), funciones): #iteramos en las funciones
    ax  = fig1.add_subplot(2,2,i) #agregamos el subplot
    ax.plot(x, f, label=f"función {i}") #graficamos
    ax.set_xticks(points)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

    for pt in points:
        ax.plot(pt, fn_1(pt), "ok")
        ax.plot(pt, fn_2(pt), "ok")

    ax.hlines(0, x[0], x[-1], "k")
    ax.vlines(0, -1, 1, "k")

    plt.legend() #mostramos el label en la leyenda
plt.show()
```

Con `zip()` estamos juntando lo creado por `range(1,3)` (que crea número del 1 al 2, esto depende de la cantidad de gráficas que vayas a hacer) y la lista `funciones` quc ontiene cada una de las funciones, los resultados es una tupla `(numero, funcion)` y eso lo separamos en las variables `i` (correspondiente al número) y `f` (correspondiente a la función). También puedes ponerle un color personalizado a cada gráfica agregando el parámetro `c` y poniendo un color aceptado por matplotlib.

Comment: ¿Se puede hacer lo mismo para tres funciones?

Comment: Sip, solo agrega la función a la lista `funciones` y cambia el `range` a `range(1, 4)` y si quieres más  funciones mejor coloca `range(1, len(funciones)+1)` y  ahora solo agrega las funciones que quieras a la lista `funciones`